# Push file to S3 with added tags using Apache Camel and Java

Tags: java, amazon-s3, apache-camel

I'm trying to read the message and its headers from the message broker and persist it to the AWS S3 bucket by replacing headers with tags. The object is getting persisted to S3 but the tags are not.

here is the routing config:

```
from(from)
  .routeId(id)
  .process(new S3FileProcessor(...))
  .to(to);
```

, and here is the S3FileProcessor#process method:

```
@Override
public void process(Exchange exchange) {
  Map<String, Object> inputHeaders = exchange.getIn().getHeaders();
  ...
  Map<String, Object> s3Metadata = Map.of("x-amz-tagging", "tag1=tag1&tag2=tag2");
  outMessage.setHeader(AWS2S3Constants.METADATA, s3Metadata); // option 1: does not work
  outMessage.setHeader("x-amz-tagging", s3ObjectTagsAsUrlQueryString); // option 2: does not work as well
}
```